No transaction active after migrating from Java 8 to 11, Spring 4.3.30 to 5.1.20, and Hibernate 5.2.13 to 5.4.33
I've recently migrated a Java-based web application and I'm encountering transaction issues after the following upgrades:

Java: from 8 to 11
Spring: from 4.3.30.RELEASE to 5.1.20.RELEASE
Hibernate: from 5.2.13.Final to 5.4.33.Final

After the migration, certain service methods annotated with @Transactional no longer trigger transactions, resulting in the following error:
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: no transaction is in progress; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:403)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:256)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:531)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:154)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:144)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$ExposeRepositoryInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:364)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy202.findOneForUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at com.quicktech.quicktech.common.service.impl.TicketServiceImplV2.getTicketAndLock(TicketServiceImplV2.java:1543)
    at com.quicktech.quicktech.common.service.impl.TicketServiceImplV2.getReadableTicketAndLock(TicketServiceImplV2.java:1548)
    at com.quicktech.quicktech.common.service.impl.TicketServiceImplV2.checkLockAndGetEditableTicket(TicketServiceImplV2.java:1526)
    at com.quicktech.quicktech.common.service.impl.TicketServiceImplV2.createTicketUpdate(TicketServiceImplV2.java:395)
    at com.quicktech.quicktech.common.service.impl.TicketServiceImplV2.createTicketUpdateFromWeb(TicketServiceImplV2.java:1808)
    at com.quicktech.quicktech.servlet.controller.TicketsControllerV2.createTicketUpdate(TicketsControllerV2.java:219)
    at com.quicktech.quicktech.servlet.controller.TicketsControllerV2$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$74a5ba79.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:752)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:69)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
    at com.quicktech.quicktech.servlet.controller.TicketsControllerV2$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3962e15b.createTicketUpdate(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at com.quicktech.quicktech.common.filter.LogRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(LogRequestFilter.java:35)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1631)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1604)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1652)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor113.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:404)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy261.getSingleResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:221)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:91)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:125)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    ... 99 more

Here is an example service method that fails to initiate a transaction:
Java
@Service
public class TicketServiceImplV2 {

    public TicketServiceImplV2() {
        System.out.println("TicketServiceImplV2 instantiated: " + this);
    }
    
    @Autowired
    private TicketUpdatePersistence ticketPersistence;

    @Transactional
    public void createTicketUpdate(TicketUpdate update) {
        Ticket ticket = ticketPersistence.findById(update.getTicket().getId())
            .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("Ticket not found"));

        System.out.println("Transaction active: " + TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive());

        Ticket lockedTicket = ticketPersistence.findOneForUpdate(ticket.getId())
            .orElseThrow(() -> new BadRequestException("No ticket found for update"));
    }
}

Problem:
TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive() returns false, and a TransactionRequiredException is thrown when attempting to update the Ticket in the database. In some other services I have TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive() as true
What I've Tried:
Transaction configuration: There is only one log "TicketServiceImplV2 instantiated", so this suggests that your service is only being instantiated in one context (likely the main context) and not in both contexts.
I verified that the transaction manager is properly configured:
XML
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

Public method: The method is public, and @Transactional is correctly applied to it.
No self-invocation: I’ve ensured that there’s no self-invocation of the @Transactional method, as it is being called externally.
Locking mechanism: The persistence layer uses pessimistic locking in the findOneForUpdate method:
Java
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
@Query("SELECT t FROM Ticket t WHERE t.id = :id")
Ticket findOneForUpdate(@Param("id") String ticketId);

My db.xml configuration file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.3.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" primary="true">
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${db.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="#{props.getDbUsername()}" />
        <property name="password" value="#{props.getDbPassword()}" />
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="${db.tomcat.maxActive}" />
        <property name="minimumIdle" value="${db.tomcat.minIdle}" />
        <property name="leakDetectionThreshold" value="${db.leak-detection-threshold}" />
        <property name="connectionTimeout" value="${db.connection-timeout}" />
        <property name="idleTimeout" value="${db.idle-timeout}" />
        <property name="autoCommit" value="true" />
        <property name="maxLifetime" value="1800000" />
    </bean>

    <bean name="quartzDS" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" primary="false">
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="#{props.getDbQuartzUrl()}"/>
        <property name="username" value="#{props.getDbUsername()}" />
        <property name="password" value="#{props.getDbPassword()}" />
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="${db.tomcat.maxActive}" />
        <property name="minimumIdle" value="${db.tomcat.minIdle}" />
        <property name="leakDetectionThreshold" value="${db.leak-detection-threshold}" />
        <property name="connectionTimeout" value="${db.connection-timeout}" />
        <property name="idleTimeout" value="${db.idle-timeout}" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
          id="entityManagerFactory">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="spring-jpa"/>

        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="false"/>
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <array>
                <value>com.quicktech.quicktech.common.model</value>
            </array>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.quicktech.quicktech.common.persistence"
                      entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory"
                      transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"
                      repository-impl-postfix="CustomImpl"/>

</beans>

My Spring common XML configuration
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.1.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/application.properties,classpath:/spring.properties"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.quicktech.quicktech.common"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.quicktech.quicktech.aspect"/>

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

</beans>

quicktech-servlet.xml
            <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true">
                <bean class="com.quicktech.quicktech.common.serialization.json.converter.QuicktechMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
                    <property name="ignoreString" value="true"/>
                    <property name="objectMapper" ref="objectMapper"/>
                </bean>
            </mvc:message-converters>
    
        </mvc:annotation-driven>
    
        <!--Controllers-->
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.quicktech.quicktech.servlet.controller"/>
    
        <!-- Controller advisers -->
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.quicktech.quicktech.servlet.advisor"/>
    
    </beans>

web.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/spring-*.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>custom-filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.quicktech.quicktech.common.filter.LogRequestFilter</filter-class>
        <!-- Other options -->
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>custom-filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/v2/tickets/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/company/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/users/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/products/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/taxes/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/serviceAgreements/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/saleQuotes/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
        <!-- Other options -->
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.quicktech.quicktech.common.config.CorsFilter
        </filter-class> <!-- your package name and filter class -->
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/passwordRecords/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/google/code/otp/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:/servlet/quicktech-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <multipart-config>true</multipart-config>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/404.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>400</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/400.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>360</session-timeout>
        <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
    </session-config>

    <jsp-config>
        <jsp-property-group>
            <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
            <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
        </jsp-property-group>
    </jsp-config>

</web-app>

configuration class location

My questions:

What could be causing transactions to not activate after the migration from Spring 4.3 to 5.1 and Hibernate 5.2 to 5.4?
Are there any known changes in Spring 5 or Hibernate 5.4 that might affect the transaction management behavior?
Could this issue be related to the migration from Java 8 to Java 11, and if so, how do I resolve it?

Additional Info:

Database: PostgreSQL 12
Spring Version: 5.1.20.RELEASE
Hibernate Version: 5.4.33.Final
Java Version: 11.0.24
Application Server: Apache Tomcat 9.0.55

example for service without transaction

example for service with transaction


What is loading your db.xml (or rather add your web.xml or initializer that shows that), do you have an additional persistence.xml? Please add the full stacktrace to your question and not some snippet.

added full log, doesn't have persistence.xml. have only. db xml

It ultimatly fails on the ticketPersistence.findOneForUpdate( which feels like you either have some special query there or this is implemented on your own custom implementation.

The code of your TicketServiceImpl isnt' the actual code as well, the constructor is named differently, the Impl also implies an interface declaration that appears missing. Please add the actual code not an interpretation.

Also the findOneForUpdate method signature is not coherent with the usage that is done in the TicketServiceImpl, since in the latter it is like to return an Optional<Ticket> while the method returns an unwrapped type; please fix the examples.

It's just example. main problem that in some services I have TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive() as true and in some as false. Even if spring @Transactional annotation is there.

Do you have a example codebase to reproduce this issue? If yes, please provide your codebase via github

Can you check (i.e. using a debugger) if the TicketServiceImplV2 instance is correctly wrapped by Spring proxies for transaction management, for example putting a breakpoint in the method, and see the call stack? Just to see if the instance is correctly injected and the call passes through all the right levels.

I think your problem is in TicketsControllerV2 controller, can you show its code?

Update after you provided screenshots:
When inspecting the screenshot with NO transaction, you can see that the controller is directly calling the service (with no transaction).
When inspecting the screenshot WITH transaction, you can see that the controller is calling the service (with transaction), but there are 13 stack elements hidden. If you take a look at them, I am pretty sure that there is the spring-transaction-AOP logic hidden.
Solution:
I assume that, due to the update, your service class gets instantiated very early. At a time in which the spring-transaction-AOP logic is not yet in place.
Methodology:

Set a break point in your service's constructor
Take a look at the call stack (screenshot, write it down ..)
Set a breakpoint in a service class WITH transaction
Take a look at the call stack (screenshot, write it down ..)
Compare
There must be a reason your service class without transaction get instantiated earlier than the other classes.

Original answer:
Try to debug and see if your class is wrapped with the correct spring-proxy.
If not, take a look at the callstack of your breakpoint. Maybe due to the spring upgrade, the instantiation of your beans got shuffled around, and the TicketServiceImplV2 gets instantiated earlier than the spring-transaction-aop logic.

added to question

updated screenshot with unhide  call stack

Looks like TicketServiceImplV2 and some other services doesn't have transaction context and I need to find out the reason. Both services and their interfaces are located in same folders

I also have warning 20:06:55,528  INFO PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker:330 main - Bean 'ticketServiceImplV2' of type [com.quicktech.quicktech.common.service.impl.TicketServiceImplV2] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

and same  warning "not eligible for auto-proxying" I have on 798 beans during app startup

Spring 5 became more strict on checking Transactional.
You have to annotate the chain of methods involved in a Transaction as well, the repository ones too, so for example findOneForUpdate should be also annotated with @Transactional.
This would fix your case, but some other things might be wrong in your project that might trigger this issues, for instance, your JPA managing, the proxys you might be using, etc.

Also, "just" adding @Transactional on the repository does not make the Service class method transactional! I think that's what he is going for in his question.

There are multiple issues listed down as follows:
Fix the context:component-scan code in quicktech-servlet.xml:
Replace
<context:component-scan base-package="com.quicktech.quicktech.common"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.quicktech.quicktech.aspect"/>

to
<context:component-scan base-package="com.quicktech.quicktech.common, com.quicktech.quicktech.aspect"/>

Fix the context:component-scan code in common XML configuration:
Replace:
<context:component-scan base-package="com.quicktech.quicktech.servlet.controller"/> 
<context:component-scan base-package="com.quicktech.quicktech.servlet.advisor"/>

to
<context:component-scan base-package="com.quicktech.quicktech.servlet.controller, com.quicktech.quicktech.servlet.advisor"/>

Found the major issue: You are trying to save data in the PostgreSQL DB and datasource for your PostgreSQL DB is quartzDS. But where is the separate transaction manager, JPA repository and entity manager factory for that datasource? Answer - Not created. Please create a separate transaction manager, jpa repository and entity manager factory for it.
Refer to the code given below, adjust and add in the db.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.3.xsd">
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource">
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${db.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="#{props.getDbUsername()}" />
        <property name="password" value="#{props.getDbPassword()}" />
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="${db.tomcat.maxActive}" />
        <property name="minimumIdle" value="${db.tomcat.minIdle}" />
        <property name="leakDetectionThreshold" value="${db.leak-detection-threshold}" />
        <property name="connectionTimeout" value="${db.connection-timeout}" />
        <property name="idleTimeout" value="${db.idle-timeout}" />
        <property name="autoCommit" value="true" />
        <property name="maxLifetime" value="1800000" />
    </bean>
    <bean name="quartzDS" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource">
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="#{props.getDbQuartzUrl()}"/>
        <property name="username" value="#{props.getDbUsername()}" />
        <property name="password" value="#{props.getDbPassword()}" />
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="${db.tomcat.maxActive}" />
        <property name="minimumIdle" value="${db.tomcat.minIdle}" />
        <property name="leakDetectionThreshold" value="${db.leak-detection-threshold}" />
        <property name="connectionTimeout" value="${db.connection-timeout}" />
        <property name="idleTimeout" value="${db.idle-timeout}" />
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
          id="entityManagerFactory" primary="true">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="spring-jpa"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="false"/>
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <array>
                <value>com.quicktech.quicktech.common.model</value>
            </array>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
          id="entityManagerFactoryQuartzDS" primary="false">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="quartzDS"/>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="spring-jpa"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="false"/>
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <array>
                <value>com.quicktech.quicktech.common.model</value>
            </array>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManagerQuartzDS" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="quartzDS"/>
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryQuartzDS"/>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.quicktech.quicktech.common.persistence"
                      entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory"
                      transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"
                      repository-impl-postfix="CustomImpl"/>
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.quicktech.quicktech.common.persistence"
                      entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactoryQuartzDS"
                      transaction-manager-ref="transactionManagerQuartzDS"
                      repository-impl-postfix="CustomImpl"/>
</beans>

The changes that I added (to summarize):

Removed the datasource to be the primary bean instead made entityManagerFactory bean as the primary bean by default for the whole application.

Added and created a secondary LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean with the name entityManagerFactoryQuartzDS for the quartzDS. That's much needed.

Added and created a secondary JpaTransactionManager with the name transactionManagerQuartzDS that refers to entityManagerFactoryQuartzDS and quartzDS. That's much needed.

Add another duplicate entry for jpa:repositories but just that it will refers to transactionManagerQuartzDS and entityManagerFactoryQuartzDS. There will be two separate JPA repositories configuration.


Update TicketServiceImplV2 to this:
@Service
public class TicketServiceImplV2 {
  
    private TicketUpdatePersistence ticketPersistence;

    public TicketServiceImplV2(TicketUpdatePersistence ticketPersistence) {
        this.ticketPersistence = ticketPersistence;
    }

    @Transactional(transactionManager = "transactionManagerQuartzDS")
    public void createTicketUpdate(TicketUpdate update) {
        Ticket ticket = ticketPersistence.findById(update.getTicket().getId())
            .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("Ticket not found"));

        System.out.println("Transaction active: " + TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive());

        Ticket lockedTicket = ticketPersistence.findOneForUpdate(ticket.getId())
            .orElseThrow(() -> new BadRequestException("No ticket found for update"));
    }
}

Note: @Transactional(transactionManager = "transactionManagerQuartzDS") this line will make sure that the Service is using the correct transaction manager which is available for your PostgresSQL DB.
FYI, by default earlier, @Transactional was using some other DB via datasource as the primary bean. That's why it was reporting that error.
See if this helps.

@ОлегГаврилів Is this helpful?

no, looks like main problem is because I have a lot of  "not eligible for auto-proxying" messages on startup for 798 beans

Issue with a lot of not eligible for auto-proxying beans on startup gone after I removed sprig security annotation @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
